# What does '\' actually do in C?

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor

As far as I know `\` in C just appends the next line as if there was not a line break.

Consider the following code:

```
main(){\
return 0;
}
```

When I saw the pre-processed code(`gcc -E`) it shows

```
main(){return
       0;
}
```

and not

```
main(){return 0;
}
```

What is the reason for this kind of behaviour? Also, how can I get the code I expected?

Comment: what do you mean by "the pre-processed code"?

Comment: @DavidBrown: Presumably the output of `gcc -E` (or equivalent).

Comment: ok, different question

Comment: @Zane: I wouldn't use it for long strings, since C already joins adjacent string literals (so e.g. `"foo" /* bar */ "baz"` is equivalent to `"foobaz"`). The only thing I think the backslash-after-new-line is really useful for is macro definitions (where it lets you put the definition across multiple lines).

Comment: This is a question about some specific standalone C preprocessor, not a question about the C language. Expanding: C compilers produce executable programs, they don't produce C code ... so you can't get the code you expected out of a C compiler.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Why are you interested in how the preprocessor works at all? What is the context? Or are you just curious by yourself?

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi I expected that the preprocessed code would be 2 lines, but when I checked it is still 3 lines. I was just curious

Comment: @ruakh backslash at the end of a line predated string literal concatenation and was the way to get long strings back then. Now it's only goo for macros, as you mention, and obfuscation.

Comment: banarun, that wasn't the question. Please answer the question so that we can help you.

Comment: @banarun: I cannot recreate this behaviour with GCC 4.2 on OSX.  What version are you using?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth gcc 4.7.3

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, your expected result is the one required by the C and C++ standards. The backslash simply escapes the newline, i.e. the backslash-newline sequence is deleted.

GCC 4.2.1 from my OS X installation gives the expected result, as does Clang. Furthermore, adding a `#define` to the beginning and testing with

```
#define main(){\
return 0;
}
main()
```

yields the correct result

```
}
{return 0;
```

Perhaps `gcc -E` does some extra processing after preprocessing and before outputting it. In any case, the line break seen by the rest of the preprocessor seems to be in the right place. So it's a cosmetic bug.

**UPDATE:** According to the [GCC FAQ](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FAQ#cpp_continuation_discarded), `-E` (or the default setting of the `cpp` command) attempts to put output tokens in roughly the same visual location as input tokens. To get "raw" output, specify `-P` as well. This fixes the observed issues.

Probably what happened:

1. In preserving visual appearance, tokens not separated by spaces are kept together.
2. Line splicing happens before spaces are identified for the above.
3. The `{` and `return` tokens are grouped into the same visual block.
4. `0` follows a space and its location on the next line is duly noted.

**PLUG:** If this is really important to you, I have implemented [my own preprocessor](http://code.google.com/p/c-plus) with correct implementation of both raw-preprocessed and whitespace-preserving "pretty" modes. Following this discussion I [added](http://code.google.com/p/c-plus/source/detail?r=d462b650c355b606545158f4da7365180b699752) line splices to the preserved whitespace. It's not really intended as a standalone tool, though. It's a testbed for a compiler framework which happens to be a fully compliant C++11 preprocessor library, which happens to have a miniature command-line driver. (The error messages are on par with GCC, or Clang, sans color, though.)

Comment: " your expected result is the one required by the C and C++ standards. " -- Not at all -- the standards do not require that implementations output C code, and they say nothing about the format of C code generated by programs that do. "So it's a cosmetic bug." -- It's not a bug at all, because the format of the output of gcc -E is not specified, other than that it will compile correctly.

Comment: @JimBalter The output of phase 4 is well-defined enough to be observable. It consists of spaces, newlines, and preprocessing tokens. The standards don't require it to be observable, but if the preprocessor output is indeed what he's observing, the standard specifies what it should be, and where the newline goes. (There is no textual indication of token boundaries, so the text representation certainly falls short a bit.) I'm sure this is documented, and since GCC is supposed to conform to its own documentation, it might be more serious as a bug. http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57714

Comment: I've reconsidered this and agree that it's a GCC bug, because running the output of gcc -E through the compiler will give the wrong line number for an error if, say, the `0` in the OP's code is replaced by `x` or something else not allowed at that point. There's a response from Andrew Pinski to your bugzilla report claiming that it's the right output, but he's clearly wrong.

Comment: It's possible that the GCC folks have misinterpreted "each instance of a backslash character (\) immediately followed by a new-line character is deleted" to mean the the backslash is deleted but the newline is not. The language is ambiguous, but the intent is certainly that "instance of" refers to the two characters.

Comment: @JimBalter It looks like a simple accident, or poor test coverage. Andrew was my buddy at Apple back ~10 years ago but he doesn't seem to remember me… and he has better things to do :P . Judging by the clock, he might be on his way home now.

Comment: Oops, my comment about line numbers is wrong. If there's an error in *both* `return` and `0`, then the error messages will indicate different line numbers rather than the same one. It's impossible to get it completely right because #line directives can't occur mid-line. Of course, line directives aren't part of any phase of C translation, so we're back to my original point that the standard doesn't specify the output of gcc -E and so there's no bug in it. One can argue that the documentation should make it clearer that the output does not adhere to anything specified by the standard.

Answer (score 10):

From [K&R section A.12 Preprocessing](http://zanasi.chem.unisa.it/download/C.pdf):

> A.12.2 Line Splicing
>
> Lines that end with the backslash character \ are
>   folded by deleting the backslash and the following newline character.
>   This occurs before division into tokens.

Comment: This is especially useful when people want macro's to extend across multiple lines

Comment: @MarounMaroun, oli added a online refrence for pdf

Comment: @OliCharlesworth The question "What does '\' do in C?" is perfectly answered by this, I think.

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi: Sure.  But the real question appears to be "why am I seeing this particular behaviour?".

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't matter :/ The tokenizer will not see any difference. <sup>1</sup>

**Update** In response to the comments:

> There seems to be a fair amount of confusion as to what the expected output of the preprocessor should be. My point is that the expectation /seems/ reasonable at a glance but doesn't actually need to be specified in this way for the output to be valid. The amount of whitespace present in the output is simply irrelevant to the parser. What matters is that the preprocessor should treat the *continued line* as one line while interpreting it.
>
> In other words: **the preprocessor is not a text transformation tool, it's a token manipulation tool.**

If it matters to you, you're probably

- using the preprocessor for for something other than C/C++
- treating C++ code as text, which is a ... code smell. (libclang and various less complete parser libraries come to mind).

<sup>1</sup> (The preprocessor is free to achieve the specified result in whichever way it sees fit. The result you are seeing is possibly the most efficient way the implementors have found to implement this particular transformation)

Comment: Or you're defining macros, in which case it's pretty important ;)

Comment: Oli: disagree. The specified behaviour of macros is independent of whitespace present in preprocessed code

Comment: You can span the definition of a single macro over multiple lines, but only if you terminate each line with \.

Comment: Oli I know. My point is that the amount of whitespace generated between tokens in the output is irrelevant (and likely unspecified)

Comment: This is somewhat pedantic, but bear in mind that line concatenation happens *before* the preprocessor runs, so if somehow that step were going wrong (and not correctly concatenating lines), then the preprocessor would "see" the wrong thing...

Comment: @Oli That's not pedantic, that's irrelevant/speculative. Clearly, there is no such bug in the implementation :)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Please provide proof. And post _that_ as the answer

Comment: @not-sehe: The OP has provided proof; he/she is not getting the output one would "expect" after running `gcc -E` (apparently).  (And FWIW, I don't observe this behaviour when I try it...)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth that proves _nothing_. He's **expecting** the wrong thing (on the wrong level of abstraction). See here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=847ed7f2b66e9ed8225c3811148c28c9-abdfdee57d25b89ef85a95738abd8a1c GNU cpp is *not* blatantly broken.

Comment: Agreed, I cannot recreate the OP's observation.  In which case, either he/she is using a particular buggy version, or the observation is incorrect.  However, the OP **is** expecting the right thing; the standard says precisely what should occur (although as you point out in your answer, the discrepancy is irrelevant in this context).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I'm going to be lazy here (and need to go into the office): so I'd be most obliged if you could actually dig up the _supposed_ standard quotation that specifies this "precisely". I'm convinced the the wording will turn out to allow what we see, for precisely the reasons I describe in my answer.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth There's no bug. I get the same result as the OP, but it does the right thing for macros ... all of which is within what is permitted by the C standard. " the OP is expecting the right thing" -- as has been explained to you, this is wrong ... there is no "right thing" to expect; the C standard says nothing about any -E flag or any other way to observe the results of individual phases.

Comment: Thanks @Jim. That's exactly my point all along. (People are frequently astounded at the level of freedom that standards implementors get when implementing the specs.)

Comment: @JimBalter: Hmm.  The C(99) standard quite clearly states what should happen in the different translation stages.  If GCC -E (which is documented to show "the output after preprocessing") produces something that doesn't correspond, then one could argue that it's non-compliant (regardless of the fact that it doesn't actually matter in this instance).

Comment: @Oli What happens in the stages is *internal* ... again, the C standard does not provide any way for you to see it. gcc -E is not a C compiler, it does something else altogether. gcc complies with the standard ... it compiles macros correctly. (And we would have noticed long ago if it didn't.)

Comment: @JimBalter: I think we may veering into a pointless discussion ;)  I see your point, but I'd still argue that gcc -E is (at best) irritatingly misleading if it's outputting something other than what the standard implies should be generated in the conceptual model (given that it could so easily generate the "correct" thing).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth 'which is documented to show "the output after preprocessing"' -- not in my documentation. Anyway, "the output after preprocessing" is internal data structures ... modern compilers do not produce a text stream between the preprocessor and other stages.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth " I'd still argue that gcc -E is (at best) irritatingly misleading" **so what**?? That's a radical goalpost shifting strawman ... the discussion has been about the C standard and compliance. The end.

Comment: @JimBalter: I was paraphrasing from memory... The actual description appears to be "Stop after the preprocessing stage".

Comment: @JimBalter: It's ok, I concede that the standard in no way constrains the implementation here.  But I maintain that this GCC behaviour is misleading (and appears to have been changed over time; 4.2 acts differently to 4.7.2), and that this could be viewed as a "bug" (bugs aren't restricted solely to standards compliance).

Comment: That's okay, we can fix our own conceptual models even more easily than FOSS compilers!

Comment: @JimBalter: No need for that tone.  I admitted I was wrong, and so made a different point.  That's not "abuse"...

Comment: @JimBalter: Sigh...  By repeating the point, I was hoping I might provoke an interesting "I agree" or "I disagree" response.  It certainly wasn't irrelevant to the original question.

Comment: @JimBalter: I'm strongly interested in whether people agree or not, because I'm interested in knowing when my model of the world is wrong.  But I agree, we *are* abusing the comment system, so let's leave it here?